# When should I use Lists vs Menus in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having trouble figuring out the difference between Lists and Menus in Material-UI.

### Docs

Lists - https://material-ui-next.com/demos/lists/

Menus - https://material-ui-next.com/demos/menus/

### Description

My thinking is that Menus are used for routing and navigation while Lists are used for configuration or static content, but then I saw these quotes:

> Menus appear upon interaction with a button, action, or other control. They display a list of choices, with one choice per line.

Reading this, Menus aren't intended to always show, they're designed to be hidden and only shown temporarily.

> Menus should not be used as a primary method for navigation within an app.

This makes it seem like a sidebar with a list of navigation elements should be a List. If so, what if I take the same component and want to also use it in a dropdown menu? Do I have to make a separate component using Menu components?

### Question

Since the docs are unclear to me, what instances would I want to use Menus vs Lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These components follow the [Material Design standards](https://material.io/), so their intended use would follow the standards.

For [Menu](https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html):

> Menus display a list of choices on a transient sheet of material.

For [List](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html):

> Lists present multiple line items vertically as a single continuous element.

So while they're similar, I think the key difference is that `Menu` is intended for a transient selection, presented within something like a Dialog or Modal.

Comment: What's transient selection?

Comment: A set of options that are meant for temporary display.  Something like a dropdown, or a popup menu.  Maybe even a temporary Drawer.

Comment: So it looks like if I have 2 lists that display the exact same information, I would have to create a `MenuList` version of that component instead of a `List` when it's temporary right?

Comment: @Sawtaytoes or create a generic component that accepts a `component` prop that defaults to either `List` or `MenuList` and uses that prop when rendering.  This is done in `ButtonBase` and could be a good example for you to review: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/eea2ecc07482c298d3a53a8240d4cc8a4d103dc9/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js#L264